# Display custom page for Forbidden site (Failed instead of 403)

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

Ok so for multiple reasons, I changed the network settings of an app service so that it cannot be accessed using its .azurewebsites.net url
It works but it displays the default "Forbidden" page. What I would like to do is have it display something like this:
If I can extend it to returning a failed status instead of a 403, that would also be awesome.

[image: Site Can't be reached]

Answer (score 0):

Creating custom error pages in cases of 4XX and 5XX errors is not supported out of the box with Azure App Services as of today, but it is a heavily upvoted and [requested feature](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169385-web-apps/suggestions/9912714-enable-users-to-create-custom-error-pages-for-403) on their UserVoice forum. Please upvote it so the Product Group can prioritize it accordingly.

To work around it, you could use an **Application Gateway** to create custom error pages instead of displaying default error pages. You can use your own branding and layout using a custom error page.

Custom error pages are supported for **maintenance** and **unauthorized access** scenarios, and can be defined both at *global* and *listener* levels.

The configuration through Azure Portal and Azure PowerShell is explained in detail in this article: [Create Application Gateway custom error pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/custom-error)

Comment: Hi there, thanks for the answer. But what I was really looking for is a failed response code as a custom error page still indicates that there is a webserver behind it. My goal is something like when you go to foobase.azurewebsites.net

Comment: @EduLorenzo Ohk, not super sure if that's doable.